# Looking to extract files Created between two times over several days

Tags: bash, macos, unix

Problem:
I have a folder with over a million files. A snapshot is taken every 30 minutes and saved to this folder (for the past several years)

Objective: I would like to take out files created on each day between 0800 and 1700

So far I have worked out with my basic knowledge of bash that for a given Day you can use the following command:

```
find directory -type f -newermt "2016-11-23 08:00:00" ! -newermt "2016-11-23 17:00:00"
```

Problem is how do I do it for several dates for that time period?

Also Once I can figure that out, I suppose I can pipe copy it to another folder.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

use File::Find;
use Time::Piece;

$ENV{TZ} = 'Europe/Berlin';

find( sub {
    my $mtime = (stat)[9];
    my $tp = localtime->strptime($mtime, '%s');

    $tp = $tp + $tp->tzoffset;
    my $hour = $tp->hour;

    say $File::Find::name
        if $hour >= 8
        && ($hour < 17
            || $hour == 17 && $tp->min == 00 && $tp->sec == 00);
}, shift);
```

[File::Find](http://p3rl.org/File::Find) recursively traverses the given directory. For each file, it runs the given code: it retrieves its modification time, creates a [Time::Piece](http://p3rl.org/Time::Piece) object from it, and checks whether its time corresponds to the range.

Comment: Thanks Choroba, I am very much an amateur at any type of code. If you have the time, could you please provide a more "for dummies" code i.e. where I need to input file path etc.

Comment: @amateurphotographer: Save the script to `findhours.pl`, run `perl findhours.pl top_directory`.

Comment: Okay, I got it working but it give me the wrong answer. See below
http://tinypic.com/r/2qkj6vs/9

Comment: The picture shows the filename with the creation date and time in the name. So the script you provided is returning images captured between the 23rd of nov 2016 at 9pm to 24th of Nov 2016 before 6am.

Comment: I modified your code to:
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

use File::Find;
use Time::Piece;

find( sub {
    my $mtime = (stat)[9];
    my $tp = 'Time::Piece'->strptime($mtime, '%s');
    my $hour = $tp->hour;
    say $File::Find::name
        if $hour >= 15
        && ($hour < 17
            || $hour == 17 && $tp->min == 00 && $tp->sec == 00);
}, shift);

It gives me files 2016-11-24 4:06 am to 2016-11-24 5.42 am

If that helps

Comment: Are you sure the time in the name corresponds to the actual modification time? Please verify with `ls -l`.

Comment: Yes it does. The date and time of the snapshot in the name is exactly the same as the date it was created on the system. I have no knowledge of perl but it looks like your code is somehow confusing 12hr and 24hr time?

Comment: Note that creation time and modification time could be different on some OSes.

Comment: Agreed, and I double checked. There is an error in code, as above I believe it may be a 12/24 hr issue.

Comment: @amateurphotographer: Maybe it's a timezone thing?

Comment: Please, try with the updated code, it should handle timezones now. Just replace the Berlin timezone with your current one.

Comment: Tried. Still getting the same result. See screenshot.
http://tinypic.com/r/2zrkzuh/9

Comment: Can you print the hour to see what's wrong? `say "$hour $File::Find::name"`

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=1;i<=7;i++))
do
        dayte=$(date -d "2016-11-24-$i days" +%Y-%m-%d)
        find directory -type f -newermt "$dayte 08:00:00" ! -newermt "$dayte 17:00:00"
done
```

Counting the days before the end date range to formulate a for loop. In this example case, it would count 7 days before 2016-11-24 and so 2016-11-17 to 2016-11-24

Answer (score 0):

**a.** Create a file

```
echo '#!/bin/bash
for i in $@
do
    find /source_dir -type f -newermt "$i 08:00:00" ! -newermt "$i 17:00:00" -exec cp {} /target_dir \;
done' > ffiles.sh
```

Instead `source_dir` you need set the directory in which you are looking for files, for example `/home/user/snapshots/`. And instead `target_dir` paste directory into which you will copy the found files.

**b.** Set the permissions to make the script executable:

```
$ chmod +x ffiles.sh
```

**c.** Run the script and find and copy the files created from 08:00 to 17:00. The date (or several) is specified as an argument when the script is run:

```
$ ./ffiles.sh 2016-11-23 2016-11-25
```

(or use this format for dates `20161123`, `20161125`)

Comment: Thanks Zombic, I am very much an amateur at any type of code. If you have the time, could you please provide a more "for dummies" code i.e. where I need to input file path etc.

Comment: @amateurphotographer, I added the description.